# fetching factory returned value in controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I want to fetch the factory returned value in controller side.Now I caught the error 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'.
I called the factory in save function.'confirmmodal' is the factory.I want to get $scope.test value which is returned while triggering ok function

```
Controller 
$scope.save = function(){
$rootScope.showspinner = true;
if(!$scope.message) $scope.message = "Sorry no request message found..";
   // $scope.customer=confirmmodal.transientModal($scope.message);
    //console.log($scope.customer);
    confirmmodal.transientModal($scope.message).then(function(data){
    $scope.value = data;
     });     
    };

    Factory
       transientModal: function(text) {
    $rootScope.transient_modal = true;
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'partials/transient-modal/confirm_modeltemplate.html',
      controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {    
                if(text) $scope.alertmsg = text; else $scope.alertmsg = "Sorry no request message found..";
                $rootScope.showspinner = true;
                $rootScope.showspinner = false;
                                    $scope.ok = function() {
                                         alert("ok button");
                                         $scope.test = 'tesating';
                                         return $scope.test;
                    //$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };  
                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
      }
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your transientModal method should return a Promise object if you want to use .then().

Comment: how to use promise in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
transientModal: function(text) {
    $rootScope.transient_modal = true;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'partials/transient-modal/confirm_modeltemplate.html',
      controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {    
                if(text) $scope.alertmsg = text; else $scope.alertmsg = "Sorry no request message found..";
                $rootScope.showspinner = true;
                $rootScope.showspinner = false;
                                    $scope.ok = function() {
                                         alert("ok button");
                                         $scope.test = 'tesating';
                                         return $scope.test;
                    //$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };  
                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
      }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function(test){
        deferred.resolve(test);
    },function(){
        deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

You can try with this, please inject $q into the factory before executing

Comment: how to check the output here? I am not able to see anything when I click on the ok button

Comment: instead of the return statement can you try using $modalInstance.close($scope.test); and then check whether the value is coming?

Comment: that also doesn't return test value